# Cut a column based on intervals of another column in r

Tags: r, dataframe, cut, levels

I want to cut test$income into 25 levels and using the intervals derived, I stored them in a variable called levels and I wish to cut train$income based on the same intervals. I tried the following code below but I am not sure why some of my values in train$income were coerced to NA.

What went wrong? Is there a better way to do this? Thank you!

```
test$income <- cut(test$income,b=25)

levels <- c(-0.853,-0.586,-0.325,-0.0643,0.196,0.457,0.718,0.978,1.24,1.5,1.76,2.02,2.28,2.54,2.8,3.06,3.32,3.59,3.85,4.11,4.37,4.63,4.89,5.15,5.41,5.68)

train$income <- cut(train$income,levels)
```

Comment: NAs can be introduced if you have values in train$income higher than 5.68...

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnGilfillan says, one reason can be that your `train$income` is higher than 5.68 or lower than -0.853. In this case you would get some of your values as NAs, while others would be numeric. This is a likely case, but another reason (for another instance) could be that you have used a character vector to specify the breaks in your actual code (`levels` from `cut` object will return a character vector). In this case you would get a vector with only NAs (written as `<NA>`).

The solution is to expand the extremes of your `levels` vector.

Try this:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- runif(100, -6, 6)

set.seed(2)
b <- runif(100, -6, 6)

levs <- levels(cut(a, 25))
levs <- gsub("\\(", "", levs)
levs <- gsub("\\]", "", levs)
levs <- c(as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(levs, ","), "[", 1)),
 as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(levs, ","), "[", 2))[length(levs)])

cut.b <- cut(b, levs)

## Both NA values are outside levs
b[is.na(cut.b)]

cut.b.new <- cut(b, c(-6, levs[c(-1, -length(levs))], 6))

## No NAs
any(is.na(cut.b.new))
```

PS: It is not recommended to use function names as object names. Therefore `levs` instead of `levels`.